# How to make Duplicity purge old backups on S3?

Tags: duplicity, duply, amazon-s3

To anyone used Duplicity with Duply (wrapper script) on S3, what is the correct command to make duplicity purge old backups?

I tried setting up the "MAX_AGE=7D" variable, and calling duply with backup_purge --force, but it still keeps all backups.

Thanks for any idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you know what to expect in this senario? The [documentation on duplicity](http://duplicity.nongnu.org/docs.html) says that it uses incremental backups, making each additional backup a patch or changeset of the previously uploaded one. Deleting any old backup files would break the chain of files needed to piece together a full data set.

It appears to have a function to periodically do a full backup to clean up the incremental change chain with new full files. Have you set that up and run one recently? How are you observing that "it still keeps all backups"? Are you looking at S3 directly?

Comment: Seems I didn't understand at time how it works indeed, shortening the amount of time incremental were kept sorted this out.